# decode base64 string in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import base64 

import csv

import pandas as pd

from pandas import read_csv

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/실증 데이터/200921_obd_data/0004514.csv',
         
dtype = {"serial_number": str, "topic": str,"payload": str,"payload_type": str,"created": str})

df

payload_df = df['payload']

payload_df

words = pd.read_table('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/실증 데이터/200921_obd_data/test.csv',names=['payload'], header=None, sep="\t")

words

data = base64.b64decode(words)
```

that's my code!!

last argument occur error about

```
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-7232c7ca2a22> in <module>
----> 1 data = base64.b64decode(words)

~\anaconda3\lib\base64.py in b64decode(s, altchars, validate)
     78     in the input result in a binascii.Error.
     79     """
---> 80     s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
     81     if altchars is not None:
     82         altchars = _bytes_from_decode_data(altchars)

~\anaconda3\lib\base64.py in _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
     44     except TypeError:
     45         raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "
---> 46                         "string, not %r" % s.__class__.__name__) from None
     47 
     48 

TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'DataFrame'/
```

this

how i can fix it well?

i have a data which is encoded base64  so i want to decoded it

Comment: You pass a dataframe to  base64.b64decode. You can only pass `bytes-like object or ASCII string`

Comment: Want you're doing is trying to decode a dataframe as base64, what you want to do is to decode each line of a single column of your dataframe, Im not very versed with pandas but you can try something like this `df['bas64 column'].apply(base64.b64decode)`